# Javascript "variable" is not defined

Tags: javascript

I've written a script that takes grades from a user for different units and then adds them to an array, shows the grades and also an average.

When I run the script it works fine, but instead of an average, it displays 'grade' is not defined.

```
var subjects = ["CF:", "DaD:", "PoP:", "N&CS:", "SAD:", "APP:"];
var grades = ["", "", "", "", "", ""];
var result;

grades[0] = prompt("Please enter your marks for CF: ");
grades[1] = prompt("Please enter your marks for DaD: ");
grades[2] = prompt("Please enter your marks for PoP: ");
grades[3] = prompt("Please enter your marks for N&CS: ");
grades[4] = prompt("Please enter your marks for SAD: ");
grades[5] = prompt("Please enter your marks for APP: ");


console.log("Units and grades are: ");

console.log(subjects[0] +"\t"+ grades[0] );
console.log(subjects[1] +"\t"+ grades[1] );
console.log(subjects[2] +"\t"+ grades[2] );
console.log(subjects[3] +"\t"+ grades[3] );
console.log(subjects[4] +"\t"+ grades[4] );
console.log(subjects[5] +"\t"+ grades[5] );

result = grades[0] + grades[1] + grades[2] + grades[3] + grades[4] + 
grade[5];

console.log("Average: " +  "\t" + result / 6);
```

anyone have any ideas? 
Apologies for the bad javascript, i'm very new to this.

Comment: Typo: `grade[5]` at the `result = ...` line.

Answer (score 6):

In this code,

```
result = grades[0] + grades[1] + grades[2] + grades[3] + grades[4] + grade[5];
```

grade[5] must be grade**s**[5]. You missed "s" point.